# CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage failed

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, yuv

I had extract Y U V data from video frame separately and saved them in data[0],data[1],data[2];The frame size is 640*480;Now I creat the pixelBuffer as below:

```
void *pYUV[3] = {data[0], data[1], data[2]};
size_t planeWidth = {640, 320, 320};
size_t planeHeight = {480, 240, 240};
size_t planeBytesPerRow = {640, 320, 320};
CVReturn renturn = CVPixelBufferCreateWithPlanarBytes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                   640, 
                                   480,
                                   kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange, 
                                   nil,
                                   nil,
                                   3, 
                                   pYUV,
                                   planeWidth,
                                   planeHeight, 
                                   planeBytesPerRow, 
                                   nil,
                                   nil, nil, &_pixelBuffer);
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(_pixelBuffer, 0);
CVPixelBufferRetain(_pixelBuffer);
    // Periodic texture cache flush every frame
CVOpenGLESTextureCacheFlush(_textureCache, 0);

// The Buffer cannot be used with OpenGL as either its size, pixelformat or attributes are not supported by OpenGL
 glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
CVReturn err = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, 
                                                            _textureCache,
                                                            _pixelBuffer,
                                                            NULL,
                                                            GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                                                            GL_LUMINANCE,
                                                            im.width,
                                                            im.height,
                                                            GL_LUMINANCE,
                                                            GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                                                            0,
                                                            &_yTexture);

if (!_yTexture || err) {
    NSLog(@"CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage failed (error: %d)", err);  
    return;
}
glBindTexture(CVOpenGLESTextureGetTarget(_yTexture), CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(_yTexture));
 CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(_pixelBuffer, 0);
```

But the err is -6638

Comment: The CVImageBufferRef needs to be IOSurface backed.