# Is kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange the same as NV12?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, yuv

The pixel format of kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange  is bi-planar component,one component for y plane and the other CbCr plane.So I think it is the same as NV12 pixel format, right?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing. This answer goes into detail describing kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6314966/420ypcbcr8biplanarvideorange-to-yuv420-how-to-copy-y-and-cbcr-plane-to-singl/6315159#6315159 And this article describes NV12 http://blog.csdn.net/yiheng_l/article/details/3790219#yuvformats_nv12 It looks like they are the same.

Comment: @Andrew Kurinnyi Do you know how to use CVPixelBufferCreateWithPlanarBytes to creat a pixel buffer? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051205/cvopenglestexturecachecreatetexturefromimage-failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051205/cvopenglestexturecachecreatetexturefromimage-failed)

Comment: I don't know. I just started working with video api on ios, and I'm using it for different purposes than you are (integration with OpenCV).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. After testing I can confirm kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange is NV12

Comment: how to decrease the video size without losing the video quality?

Comment: Could you clarify? Do you mean which compression to use? Currently HEVC has widespread support and great compression rates, it is in some cases up to 2x more efficient than h264 for example.